# IDEA выдаёт ошибку при сборке проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Всем привет! Я новичок, столкнулся с такой проблемой в IDEA Ultimate, не могу найти по ней информацию в интернете.
Я написал на Spring Boot проект, использовал Maven, версия JDK 19, всё работало отлично, никаких проблем не возникало, всё собиралось, работало через запуск main класса SpringApplication.

Но, в один момент, при сборке проекта через Build начала возникать ошибка:

```
java: No enum constant javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.SEALED
```

Везде проставлен уровень языка по умолчанию (Java 19), так же пробовал ставить 17 версию, ни в какую, просто не видит эту константу и всё...
Я залез в этот класс, проверил наличие константы, всё на месте.

Через Maven, всё идеально собирается в jar и работает, но через Build, никак не хочет. Я бы смирился, но через Maven собирать проект для тестирования очень неудобно. IDEA Community запускает проект нормально.

Пробовал:
-Переустанавливать JDK
-Переустанавливать IDEA (версия 2021.3)

Может кто сталкивался с подобным или просто знает что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант maven -clean -> maven -install

File -> Invalidate chaces

Comment: File -> Invalidate chaces - пробовал первым делом, Как вариант maven -clean -> maven -install - не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Помогла только установка следующей версии IDEA